# Sort linked questions by votes

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions

I find the "linked" and "related" feature extremely helpful in order to find answers to very similar questions. Currently, the order seems a bit random. Example:

[Using grep in R to find strings as whole words (but not strings as part of words)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227976/using-grep-in-r-to-find-strings-as-whole-words-but-not-strings-as-part-of-words)

At least for me, the [currently highest voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802404/grep-in-r-to-find-words-with-custom-extended-boundaries) is not on top of the list. In fact, it is only visible, when looking for "more".

Is there a way to sort this by "relevance", e.g., by votes received?

This would not only be very convenient for the user, but also help identify duplicate questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/7227976?sort=votes (accessible via "See more linked questions" -> "More" -> "Votes")

Comment: @CodyGray thanks that's already a useful thing. However, (I should have made this clearer), I meant in particular the order right hand section "linked" in the orginal threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some problems with this proposal for different reasons for each list.

For **Related**:

"Relevance" is the aggregation of a number of aspects of both posts compared with each other:

- How many words are shared between the posts
- Tags shared,
- Phrases shared,
- Probably many more.

Personally, I'd rather see questions which are more related by these measures appearing before those which are less related, even with higher scores.

Say I'm on a question in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) about reducing arrays to objects. There might be a highly-upvoted question about the same subject in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) that's going to do me no good whatsoever. I can't read Python well enough to translate it to JavaScript. I'd rather that be placed below a less-highly-upvoted question about reducing arrays to smaller arrays, but in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

For **Linked**:

This list I'm less worried about, but there still should be an order to it. Here's my proposed order (I am unaware of any order currently imposed on them):

1. Duplicate links (whether already closed, proposed, or closed and reopened)
2. Links in the question
3. Links in the comments and answers
4. Incoming links from other posts

If a secondary sort of those by score were desired, I can get behind that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can totally see the point for "related". regarding the "linked" list - is this order supposed to be in place? In the example thread that I posted, there are no marked duplicates, no link in the question, one external link in the answer and one stackoverflow link in (my own) comment - following the suggested order, this link should appear on top of the list? But it doesnt...

Comment: Oh, no, that's the order I think they should be in :). I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: that makes it clear:) I think it would be useful to have such a sort and I think the proposed order would make a lot of sense. But I may be the only one who finds this useful, so don't know if it's worth to spend time fixing this... ?

Comment: I think it's worth some time (you got my vote). There are probably more pressing priorities to get fixed right now though, so it could be [6 - 8 units of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/194720) before you see anything happen :).

Comment: If anything, the Related section already values upvotes too much. At least on JavaScript questions, it's often dominated by questions with thousands of upvotes that have very little to do with the one I'm looking at.